# How to drop schema with connection to table in another database?

Tags: php, database, laravel, migration

In my Laravel app, I have connections to different databases and when I need to fresh my tables in each of database with a new dummy data *(I do it with* `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` *command)*  I always have this error

> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'table_name' already exists

which is weird because I have `down()` method in my migration class

```
class CreateExampleTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::connection('conn2')->create('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::connection('conn2')->dropIfExists('table_name');
    }
}
```

Comment: This is because the `fresh` command doesn't actually run the `down()` methods, it simply drops all the tables. The other reason this probably isn't working is because unless you specify the connection the `db` artisan commands with just use the default connection.

Comment: For reference, this behavior is described and discussed extensively in https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/1026 . Laravel (Taylor) has no interest in supporting this capability, unfortunately.

Answer (score -2):

If you use `migrate:refresh` instead of `fresh` it will rollback the database using your `down()` methods.

I think the problem is not in your `down()` but with your `up()` : it is trying to create a table, but a table with that name already exists.

I would suggest doing something like:

```
if (!Schema::hasTable('tbl_name')) {
     // create table
}
```

You may also have to specify which database you are using in the migrations.